# Are those acceptable crimp connections?

Tags: electrical, connector

I am experimenting with crimp tools. Can somebody give me an indication if those crimp connections are good for automotive use?

The goal would be to have a solid, professional connection, not just holding barely together.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: They look fine to me. I'd put some heat shrink over the joints, but if you'd done that I wouldn't be able to see the important parts. :) If you want to get a little crazy, you can solder the wire-to-connector joint after it's crimped. It's not really necessary if the joint is properly crimped.

Comment: Don't forget to do a "tug test" after each crimp operation. You can't always see your connection clearly, so do a light pull. It will show any looseness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They look pretty good to me. Do make sure to use the correct size fitting for the wire you're using (or vice versa).

I would not suggest soldering - It's not necessary if the joint is well crimped, and it can introduce brittleness into the connections which could lead to them failing in a high-vibration environment such as a car engine bay.

Answer (score 0):

I was installing an electric radiator cooling fan when I asked myself the same question. With the fan energized, I measured the voltage drop across each male/female connection. Yes, these crimp fittings must be soldered.
When these crimp connectors first became available a metal cylinder was inserted in the heavy plastic upon which you crimp. The metal cylinder is no longer suppled, neither the connector body nor the heavy plastic can take its place.
The heavy plastic is discarded. Any heat shrink tubing is sliped over the wire. A 30 Watt iron is what I use. Doing things right the first time is best.